# Using 2 Texture-Atlas for UV Mapping a Mesh , How do I setup same Configuration in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine, unreal-engine

I UV mapped My Level using 2-3 Texture-Atlases in blender , Now I have to export whole Mesh in Unreal Engine 4. 
How do I setup Material-Mesh so that I read UV Map from Both Texture-Atlas.

Answer (score 0):

if you have different material slot for reference to this atlases - just make 2 materials with different textures. if slot one - you can multiply two textures or make some lerp by mask